# Put component inside the smaller one

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

I wanna get Frame(640x640) with DrawCanvas(960x960) inside like this:
[image]

So the part of DrawCanvas must be hidden and frame centered. What layout should I choose? Now I put DrawCanvas inside the frame like this:

```
    class extends JFrame {
        canvas = new DrawCanvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(960, 960));
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.add(canvas);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 640));
    }
```

Comment: I think you can do this by using [Boxlayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html), filling the spaces with gridareas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again as stated in your previous question, a way to do this is to embed the inner component within a JScrollPane, but rid the scrollpane of scrollbars.

For example, say you had a class called DrawPanel that extended JPanel and held a 12 x 12 grid of cells, but you only wanted to show 8 x 8 of them. You could have this class implement the Scrollable interface, have its `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` method return the dimensions of what you want displayed, while its `getPreferredSize` method would return the actual dimensions of the component:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {
    public static final int VISIBLE_ROW_COUNT = 8;
    private static final int ROW_COUNT = 12;
    private static final Color DARK_COLOR = Color.DARK_GRAY;
    private static final Color LIGHT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private int cellWidth;

    public DrawPanel(int cellWidth) {
        super(new GridLayout(ROW_COUNT, ROW_COUNT));
        this.cellWidth = cellWidth;
        Dimension prefSize = new Dimension(cellWidth, cellWidth);
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ROW_COUNT; j++) {
                JPanel cell = new JPanel();
                cell.setPreferredSize(prefSize);
                Color c = i % 2 == j % 2 ? DARK_COLOR : LIGHT_COLOR;
                cell.setBackground(c);
                add(cell);

                // TODO: delete the code below. For demo/debug purposes only
                String text = String.format("[%d, %d]", j, i);
                JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
                c = c == DARK_COLOR ? LIGHT_COLOR : DARK_COLOR;
                label.setForeground(c);
                cell.add(label);
                // TODO: end delete block
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        Dimension viewportSize = new Dimension(VISIBLE_ROW_COUNT * cellWidth, VISIBLE_ROW_COUNT * cellWidth);
        return viewportSize;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation,
            int direction) {
        return cellWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation,
            int direction) {
        return 1;
    }

    // note that getPreferredSize already returns the size of the 12 x 12 grid
    // since it is composed of a grid sized JPanels

}
```

You could then place this within your JScrollPane,

```
private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 80;
private DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel(CELL_WIDTH);
private JScrollPane drawPanelScrollPane = new JScrollPane(drawPanel);
```

get rid of the scrollbars,

```
    drawPanelScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    drawPanelScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

and scroll it to the spot where you want the upper left point:

```
    int x = 2 * CELL_WIDTH;
    int y = x;
    Point pt = new Point(x, y);
    drawPanelScrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(pt);
```

The example GUI:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FrameAGrid extends JPanel {
    private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 80;
    private DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel(CELL_WIDTH);
    private JScrollPane drawPanelScrollPane = new JScrollPane(drawPanel); 

    public FrameAGrid() {
        drawPanelScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        drawPanelScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(drawPanelScrollPane);

        int x = 2 * CELL_WIDTH;
        int y = x;
        Point pt = new Point(x, y);
        drawPanelScrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(pt);
    }


    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        FrameAGrid mainPanel = new FrameAGrid();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameAGrid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

This displays as:
[image]

Note that the upper left hand corner is at 2, 2 not at 0, 0

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work! I thought that JScrollPane, according to its name, requires scrollbars and I can't remove them. I'll try this.

Comment: You can embed any component in any other component without use of a JScrollPane, but the advantage of this is if you happen to later want to display the undisplayed regions, you can simply move the viewport.

Comment: Why not  at 0,0?

Comment: @diegofm: he's trying to display a larger component within a smaller one with the margins not being visible. The numbers are for demo purposes only.

Comment: @diegofm, It's my specific need.

Comment: @Russiancold: although I have to wonder if this is not an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in disguise. If you're doing this in order to find a place to put chess pieces after they've been captured, just remove them from the board and place them in an ArrayList.